# Python grab headers requests

Tags: python, selenium, get, http-headers

it's any way to grab all headers requests from site, which loads in browser network tool (maybe selemium)?

I need this URL
[image]

Comment: can we use python request module ?

Comment: Yes, any way, i need to grab all this urls

Comment: `URL` is not a header. Also parameters to send in `URL` are not headers

Comment: How i can grab this URLs?

Comment: I guess this is one of resources required for page rendering. Do you know exactly what it is? Is it some kind of image displayed on page?

Comment: I need not exactly this particular URL, I need to grab all request urls when site loads

Comment: @anekix from HTML? Few this urls are requesting from third party site from is script (like google ads) or from iframe

Comment: @KonstantinRusanov, Do you need all of links from page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know in case of any issues:

```
links = []
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//head/*[@href or @src]):
    link = element.get_attribute("href")
    links.append(element.get_attribute("href")) if link != '' else links.append(element.get_attribute("src"))
```

To get links from iframes also you might need to add this :

```
for frame in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe'):
    driver.switch_to_frame(frame)
    for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//head/*[@href or @src]):
        link = element.get_attribute("href")
        links.append(element.get_attribute("href")) if link != '' else links.append(element.get_attribute("src"))
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: It returned only URLs on page, but no urls from third-party (like Google), i need to parse URLs like this - Request URL:https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-...

Comment: This link placed inside iframe

Comment: I'm started from finding of all iframe and got 4 iframe SRCs, but without needed (google ad iframe), but if i looked inside code via code inspector tool, i can find my google iframe

Comment: Could it be embedded in another `iframe`?

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: Error: element is not attached to the page document - in chrome driver